# check if a file is in a folder or its subfolder using linux terminal

Tags: linux, terminal, grep, command, find

I want to check if the particular file is in a folder or its sub folder or not using Linux terminal.

Which should I use for this? I use `find` and `grep` command but it travels only one folder.

Comment: I wasn't aware of the `grape` command. It sounds juicy :) Funny enough, I guess you mean `grep`.

Comment: yes there is spell mistake.there is grep not grape.thanks

Answer (score 11):

In order to search from your current directory, use

```
find . -name filename
```

In order to search from root directory use

```
find / -name filename
```

If you don't know the file extension try

```
find . -name filename.*
```

Also note that find command only displays the files in the path which you have permission to view. If you don't have permission for a/b/c path then it will just display a message mentioning that path can't be searched

Answer (score 3):

If you want to search for by filename, use ***find***:

```
find /path -name "filename"
```

example:

```
find . -name myfile.txt
```

---

If need to find all files containing a specific string, use ***grep***:

```
grep -r "string" /path
```

example:

```
grep -r foobar .
```

Answer (score 2):

By default, **find** will traverse all subdirectories, for example:

```
mkdir level1
mkdir level1/level2
touch level1/level2/file

find . -name "file"
```

Output:

```
./level1/level2/file
```

Answer (score 1):

```
locate file name
```

This is the simple command

Answer (score 1):

I also prefer using a combination of `tree` and `grep`. Something like

```
tree | grep filename
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
find . -name "filename" -type f
```

`-type f` restricts to only files in the current directory (replace . with your path).